# How do I automatically run a specific import every time I use python (both interactively and when executing scripts)?

Tags: python, bash, alias

I am a big fan of the pretty printing option of [rich](https://github.com/Textualize/rich#readme).

Thus, I want to automatically run the lines

```
from rich import pretty
pretty.install()
```

every time I use python (before anything else).

How can I achieve the following behavior:

1. `python` -> run the two lines and drop me into interactive python3 shell
2. `python myscript.py` -> run the two lines, then run `myscript.py`

I have already put the two lines into a `startup.py` file and created an alias in my ~/.bashrc:

```
alias python='python3 -i /path/to/startup.py'
```

which works great when I am using the python standard shell by just calling `python` (case 1). However, I cannot use the alias to run scripts, for example with `python myscript.py` (case 2).

I am using Python 3.10.6 on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Could write a script to subprocess python (or whatever), feeds those lines to stdin, and then drops to normal console...

Comment: A possible approach  would be to modify `site.py`. `site.py` automatically gets imported while initialization (This behaviour can be disabled using the `-S`). Although modifying `site.py` is discouraged, as this can cause some very weird issues with compatibility, portability and maintanability to name a few. So if you wanna do it, do it; but be warned.

Answer (score 2):

I have actually found a solution in the meanwhile.

If you only want to achieve case #1, you should make use of the PYTHONSTARTUP environment variable, by setting it in your ~/.bashrc:

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP="/path/to/startup.py"
```

To achieve cases #1 and #2, you should name your startup file `usercustomize.py` and place it in your USER_SITE directory, which you can find with `python -m site`. This is the recommended way of modifying the behavior of `site.py`. More details in the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51071691/is-there-a-way-to-always-execute-a-script-when-python-starts-similar-site-prof).

The second approach has one downside: Compared to the PYTHONSTARTUP solution, imports being done in `usercustomize.py` are forgotten once you are dropped into the interactive shell or your script is being executed. For example, `pretty.install()` works, while `from rich import print` would *not* overwrite the default print function, as it is just an import. If you want to use default imports in the interactive shell (e.g. `import numpy as np`, because you use it so frequently), you have to use *both*, usercustomize.py and PYTHONSTARTUP. I have not yet found a solution that preserves imports while executing a script.

Thanks to @pynexj for pointing out a flaw in my previous solution.

Comment: does this work for your case #2?