# usercustomize.py runs automatically but does not store variables and functions

Tags: python, bash, command-line, ubuntu-22.04, site-packages

I have followed the instructions in this topic:
[Is there a way to always execute a script when python starts? (similar site.profile in R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51071691)

Part of the output of `python3 -m site`:

```
USER_SITE: '/home/<myuser>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

I have this usercustomize.py:

```
variabile = 'Ciao Mondo.'
print(variabile)
```

Gnome terminal:

```
<myuser>@<myuser>-<mypc>:~$ python3
Ciao Mondo.
Python 3.10.6 (main, May 29 2023, 11:10:38) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print(variabile)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'variabile' is not defined
>>>
```

As you can see, `usercustomize.py` runs automatically and prints the value of `variabile` but doesn't store it, neither when I run a script that requests it, nor from the console like in the example above.

The solution can't be in `PYTHONSTARTUP`, because I need to run this file not only when I work in interactive mode but also from scripts.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: *because I need to run this file not only when I work in interactive mode but also from scripts.* can you clarify what you mean by this?

Comment: I want this file to be run automatically not only when I run "python3" from terminal but also when I run "script.py".

Comment: So when you run `script.py` you want the printed message and the variable to be already defined?

Comment: Yes, of course it's just an example script.

Comment: Unfortunately it prints but doesn't leave the variables defined, as explained in the question, which seems clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty hack:

```py
# USER_SITE/usercustomize.py
import sys
sys.my_variable = 'Ciao Mondo.'
```

Now you have access to that variable importing `sys`

```bash
$ python3
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.my_variable)
Ciao Mondo.
```

Or more concise:

```py
# USER_SITE/usercustomize.py
import builtins
builtins.my_variable = 'Ciao Mondo.'
```

Now you have access to that variable without importing anything

```bash
$ python3
>>> print(my_variable)
Ciao Mondo.
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a variable that is available to the rest of Python, you can add it to the `builtins` module.

```
import builtins
builtins.variabile = variabile
```